# Bash script running manually but fails with cron job

Tags: bash, cron, cron-task

I have a bash script:**start_jenkins.sh** which starts a java process.

the command in the script **start_jenkins.sh** is

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "starting Jenkins service...... "

nohup java -jar /local/home/mona/jenkins/jenkins.war --httpPort=2261  > nohup_jenkins.out 2>&1 &

echo "Jenkins started .................."
```

my cronjob setup is

```
    11 18 * * 2 nohup sh /local/home/mona/jenkins/start_jenkins.sh > /local/home/mona/jenkins/logs/jenkins_`date +\%Y\%m\%d\%H\%M\%S`.log 2>&1
```

When i am running it manually i am getting log entry in the file : **jenkins.out**
& i can see java process is running.

but when i have scheduled it through cron job its not running.
i am not getting any entry in the file **jenkins.out** while log are entered for echo commands

Comment: `cron` usually has minimal `PATH` set. Try explicitly setting the required `PATH` at the start of your script.

Comment: @anishsane I am newbie for cron setup. Could you explain how do I set PATH  in cron?

Comment: If you are able to run that script successfully from the terminal, check the value of PATH variable (`echo "$PATH"`) (Sample output: `/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/bin`). Then whatever value you see, add this line at the start of your shell script: `export PATH='<value you see on the terminal>'` (e.g. `export PATH='/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/bin'`).

Comment: Thanks @anishsane. It worked :)

Comment: Glad you got your problem solved, but in the future, be sure to search first as your Q likely has an A. Just searching for `[bash] crontab script not working` returned 130 answers. Good luck.

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/449651/why-is-my-crontab-not-working-and-how-can-i-troubleshoot-it